# Batch script to ping an ip range?

Tags: networking, batch, script, psexec

I'm trying to write a batch script (`psexec` is also an option) to scan a range of IPs `192.168.1.1-255` and as output, would like a `csv` file, something like this:

```
column A        column B          Column C   Column D
PCNAME          IPADDRESS         STATUS      LASTUSER
worksta1        192.168.1.1       online      NTIDUSER
doesnoexist     192.168.1.2       offline     DOESNOTEXIST
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please explain what column D is (and how "pinging" is related to that).

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including the code they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

I think you never can get the user logged on, unless you have administrative access to the clients.
If you have a domain controller, and run the (vb or powershell) script from there as an administrator, It would be possible.
Also the firewall needs to be turned off on the clients, otherwise you cannot interrogate the clients.

Other possibility is running the script via a login script. That way the clients are locally interrogated, and can send their information to a shared folder/file on a server.

Comment: Since where did the question say it needed to log onto the clients?

Comment: @cybermonkey, despite its title, it seems the question wants to list the last logged in user? I think that's what this is referring to.

Comment: actually column D is not mandatory, can you guys create it with the first three columns?